# Magento: Javascript not executing

Tags: magento

I inserted a template on an admin page

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
<adminhtml_catalog_product_attribute_edit>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs"><js>extension/sctipt.js</js></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="head">
        <block type="page/html" output="toHtml" name="custom_script" template="extension/script.phtml" before="-"/>

    </reference>

</adminhtml_catalog_product_attribute_edit>
```

This inserts my phtml file, but it's not actually working, what i want to do is display the options panel if the catalog input type is 'custominput' (on the new attribute page) im not sure why, here's mytemplate

```
<div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   alert('hallooooooo');

if($('frontend_input')){
    Event.observe($('frontend_input'), 'change', youBoxCheck);
}

function youBoxCheck(){
if($('matage-options-panel')){
    var panel = $('matage-options-panel');
    if($('frontend_input').value=='youbox')){
        panel.show();
    }
    else {
        panel.hide();
    }
}
}
</script>
```

Not even the alert is executed, what is the problem?

Comment: Anything in your console log?

Comment: The most common cause is a javascript error earlier in the page that halts execution. Save the source of a page, upload it to a web server, and remove individual inline javascript until you find the problem code.

Comment: If that is a direct paste of your xml, then you may have a typo: `extension/sctipt.js` instead of `extension/script.js`.  If this isn't an issue then @AlanStorm is right (he usually is!! :)  )

Comment: thank you Alan (also for those tutorials btw) and Zachary I finally tracked it down, apparently there was some weird error that was giving me undeclared function (even though it was there), changed the names of the functions and voila. thanks a lot